# etc/default/keyboard not taken into account at boot

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm trying to have a mac keyboard behavior on my ubuntu/trusty32 virtual machine, and had some problems with it so far.

Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` seemed to work at first, but there was no way to keep the changes after a reboot, and the command `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` worked neither.

The /etc/default/keyboard content was :

> XKBMODEL="macbook79"
>
> XKBLAYOUT="fr"
>
> XKBVARIANT=""
>
> XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

After some reading and tests I discovered that `XKBVARIANT="mac"` has better effects. I have now to type the command `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` to obtain the behavior expected, **even after a reboot**.

So I am wondering if I misreaded the sentence

> After modifying /etc/default/keyboard, you can apply the changes to the Linux
> console by running setupcon. If X is configured to use that file too, then the
> changes will become visible to X only if
> udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
> is called, or the system is rebooted.

How to make the reboot take into account the new keyboard configuration ?

Comment: What does the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` output?

Comment: Hello, the output is `@a(ss) []`

Comment: Is it a desktop or a server you have?

Comment: "Official Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) builds" VM

Answer (score 3):

One way on an Ubuntu desktop to persistently set "French (Macintosh)" for the current user is to run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'fr+mac')]"
```

*Edit:*

On a server I think that this command gives the same result:

```
setxkbmap -layout fr -variant mac
```

However, if the system refuses to recognize `XKBVARIANT` when reading `/etc/default/keyboard` (can't explain why), you may need to have that command run at the start of each session.

Comment: did not work, still the same, despite a change with the gsettings output command :

Comment: @EtienneJouinNammalvar: Please see edited answer.

Comment: same effect indeed, I'll run the command at each session start. Many Thanks.

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'fr+mac')]" works for me !! thanks alot. Great trick. That was a problem and solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the hitch, thanks to Gunnar Hjalmarsson again.

The VM was provided with a "oh-my-zsh" configuration, and the last line of the `.zshrc` stated `setxkbmap fr`

So every attempt was reverted as soon as I launched the terminal.

Very funny afterwards. :-/